# alignment of two plots using grid.arrange()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created the following plot using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

x.test<-c(0,2,4,6,8,12,16,20,24)
y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
y.test=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

testdf<-data.frame(x.test,y.test) 


heat.time<-x.test
heat.val<-c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9)
testdf2<-data.frame(heat.time,heat.val)
plot1<-ggplot(testdf,aes(x.test,y.test))+geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,26),breaks=c(0,2,4, 6, 8, 12,16,20,24))
plot2<-ggplot(testdf2,aes(heat.time,""))+
  geom_tile(data=testdf2,aes(fill=heat.val),height=1, width=0.7)+   
  scale_fill_gradient(low="lightblue",high="blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,26),breaks=c(-1,2,4, 6, 8, 12,16,20,24))+
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    plot.background=element_blank(),
    plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,-2,0), "cm")
  )

gA <- ggplotGrob(plot2)
gB <- ggplotGrob(plot1)
maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:5], gB$widths[2:5])
gA$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gB$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
grid.arrange(gA, gB, heights=c(0.25,0.75), ncol=1)
```

[image: plot]

However, I can't seem to get the blue bars on the top plot to align with the labeled ticks on the bottom plot even though the two plots have the same horizontal axes scales.  Can anyone help or suggest an alternative method?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
```

Comment: wild guess: what about  changing also the margins of `plot1` with   `theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,-2,0), "cm"))` ?

Comment: That doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe try cowplot package, `plot_grid(g1, g2, nrow = 2, align = "v")` ?

Comment: cowplot isnt available for latest version of R.

Comment: Please add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post. I am using `R version 3.3.2` and `cowplot_0.7.0 ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: I installed older version of cowplot but your suggestion doesnt work.

Comment: Make your code reproducible, plot2 data=test is missing.

Comment: @zx8754 Updated to make reproducible.

Comment: Making your x `limits` and x `plot.margin` the same between the two plots looks like it might help get things lined up.

Comment: Just to clarify: The latest version of R is 3.3.2 of 2016-10-31, your version 3.2.3 is about one year older. So, no wonder you haven't been able to install the actual version of `cowplot` 0.7.0 which requires R >= 3.3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue was caused because (a) the parameters supplied to `scale_x_continuous()` weren't the same for both plots and (b) the limits didn't add space symmetrically on both sides.

With `cowplot` and some modifications to the parameters supplied to `scale_x_continuous()`, both plots can be aligned as expected.

With modified calls to `scale_x_continuous()`,

```
plot1 <- ggplot(testdf, aes(x.test, y.test)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 25), breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24))
plot2 <- ggplot(testdf2, aes(heat.time, "")) + 
  geom_tile(data = testdf2, aes(fill = heat.val), height = 1, width = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "blue") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1, 25), breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24)) +
  theme_void() + theme(legend.position = "top")
```

the plots can be aligned using

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot2, plot1, rel_heights=c(0.25, 0.75), ncol = 1, align = "v")
```

[image]

Note that `theme_void()` is used for `plot2` and that `plot.margin` is left unchanged.

**Versions:** R `3.3.2`, `cowplot` 0.7.0, `ggplot2` 2.2.1, `gridExtra` 2.2.1